# Using BlueMix Container Registry service without local docker running

Tags: docker, kubernetes, ibm-cloud, minikube, container-registry

I am using Minikube to test everything I deploy in IBM Bluemix kubernetes service. I have my Macbook docker environment configured to use Minikube and I don't start standard basic Docker daemon/service in my MacBook. I just:

```
eval $(minikube docker-env)
```

It works great and I use same yaml files in Minikube than then I apply to Bluemix, as I use that Docker and Minikube image registry. Problem: when I try to login to BX CR to push an image from Minikube registry I get:

```
MacBook-Pro:Docker and Kubernetes icordoba$ bx cr login
Logging in to 'registry.ng.bluemix.net'...
FAILED
Failed to 'docker login' to 'registry.ng.bluemix.net' with error: Warning: failed to get default registry endpoint from daemon (Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?). Using system default: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
.
```

It seems bx cr login command needs local docker host daemon running so I need to build image into Minkube registry, test in Minikube, shut it down, start Docker, build image again i docker registry, login to bx cr and push the image...

Can I make bx cr login command work with Minikube docker environment and not basic docker environment configured?

Comment: It looks like docker cli is a pre-req : https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/Registry/index.html?pos=2

Comment: No, I am not talking about CLI. Of course CLI is mandatory because without Docker CLI I would not even have docker command. The problem is that "bx cr..." command requires docker daemon. That is what I don't want to be running as I want to use Kubernetes (Minikube) as local docker daemon.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments the docker CLI is a pre-requirement for pushing to and pulling from the registry.

It should be possible to ssh into minikube using `minikube ssh` allowing you access to the docker daemon within minikube. You would then need to install the Bluemix cli and cr plugin. It should then be possible to push your images from there.

Alternatively you could install the IBM-Containers plugin found [here](https://clis.ng.bluemix.net/ui/repository.html). Then you can build your container in Bluemix and it will automatically push the image into the Container Registry for you to use with Kubernetes. This would allow you to build and push images without access to a docker daemon.

`bx ic build -t registry.ng.bluemix.net/<namespace>/<image>:<tag> DOCKERFILE_PATH`

(Adjust the registry region prefix based on which region you want your image to be pushed to)

Comment: OK. I get it. Your first solution works for me. I had not considered ssh into minikube virtual machine and install there BX CLI plugins and not use the MacOS ones. The second solution does not work for me because I do want images to be in Kubernetes to test images before pushing and applying on IBM Container service, so I will go for suggestion 1 (I need to figure out how to mount MacOS directories in that Minikube VM). Thanks.

Comment: I have tried the solution and it works but overtime I stop and start minikube, bx cr CLI is deleted, obviously as a new clean VM is created. I have created a new question here for that specific issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46100502/how-to-permanently-tune-minikube-vm

Comment: You can use the Bluemix Container Registry to pull images into your local minikube without them being applied to your cluster in the Container Service - as long as they have different names.

Comment: How can I do that without installing "bx cr" in the Minikube virtual machine?

Comment: You just use different namespaces/image names:

`registry.ng.bluemix.net/dev/image:1`
`registry.ng.bluemix.net/prod/image:1`.

You will need bx cr and docker installed on your local machine though.

Comment: The problem is prior to pushing images... I can't even login using "bx cr login" if local Docker is not running. Even executing the "eval" command for Minikube. For some reason, bx cr plugin checks local Docker.

Comment: Yes. bx cr login writes to you local docker config.json to enable you to docker push/pull using your local docker Daemon. Is there any reason you can't use a local docker Daemon?

Comment: Yes, I need to use Minikube, not docker daemon. I am not sure both can run OK in my notebook... Minikube seems to crash if running simultaneously with Docker (not sure though) but if docker daemon is a must for bx cr commands, I guess I'll need to find a workaround.

Comment: The docker daemon is required for pushing and pulling images but all other things can be done without it. There shouldn't be any reason you cant run minkube and docker locally.